# Minimum k-spanning tree including a given node

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a Graph (V, E), it is very easy to find the minimum spanning tree using Kruskal's Algorithm.

A **k-minimum spanning tree** is restricted to **k** nodes, and finding it is actually NP-hard.

However, the problem at hand requires that **a given node is present in the tree**. Does this extra requirement make it easier or harder? How should I solve this?

*Formally, given a graph G = (V, E), one must find the tree with K nodes, with minimum weight, and in which the node **v** is present, for a given **v**.*

Comment: I thought spanning trees contain all vertices by definition?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. It's restricted to K nodes out of |V|.

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger There is an interesting related problem which is to find the MST that contains a given edge, with 1 edge can be solved in polytime.  May I ask your motivation for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think the extra requirement does not make the problem any easier to solve than the k-minimum spanning tree. If you could solve it in polynomial time $p(n)$, where $n$ is the number of nodes, then you could simply solve it for every one of the $n$ nodes and take the solution that has minimum weight, this solving the $k$-minimum spanning tree in $n\cdot p(n)$, which is still polynomial.

Comment: By the extra requirement, I meant that the k-tree contains a certain node.

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger Oh dear, I missed that part. I will rethink my question.

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger I changed my answer entirely.

Comment: @5xum Agree with this answer, I'm not sure why anyone would expect that adding an extra condition would make the problem easier rather than harder.

Comment: So, in short, bruteforce... :(